# How to run migrations in Heroku after deploying?

Tags: heroku, migration, production

I was hitting an endpoint on my deployed backend and saw some errors regarding `errorMissingColumn`. I realized Heroku hasn't ran migrations.

I'm using sequelize so I ran

`heroku run sequelize db:migrate` it recognized the command but for some reason it timed out:

```
Running sequelize db:migrate on ⬢ reeltime-server-development... !
 ▸    ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000
```

This is my `config.json` for the database:

```
  "development": {
    "database": "reel_time_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "operatorsAliases": false
  },
  "test": {
    "database": "reel_time_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "logging": false,
    "operatorsAliases": false
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
    "operatorsAliases": false
  }
}
```

And I'm also using a Postgres Resource on Heroku.

Answer (score 4):

`heroku run:detached sequelize db:migrate` worked.